# How can i make a button clickable after poping up on hoovering an image

Tags: html, css

So, on hoovering an image, a button appears onto the image, but it is not clickable . The same applies for links or anything inside the div holding the image. I was wondering how i can get over with this.

My html

```
<div class="content_img">
          <img [src]="mydata.image.original" >
          <div >
            <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary"> Description </button>
</div>
</div>
```

My Css

```
/* Parent Container */
.content_img{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
 }
 
 /* Child Text Container */
 .content_img div{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
 background:black; 
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.7;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear; 
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
 }
 
 /* Hover on Parent Container */
 .content_img:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .content_img:hover div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.75; 
 }
```

Can anyone help me out please

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by that ? I tested the code and `<a>` tag works. I tested it like follow :

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="">
  <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary">Description</button>
</a>
```

The button link is clickable. If it is a button, did you set a `onclick` event so that button call your function?

Comment: I tried as you've shown still nothing .Please  check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=nsS8OpPBM8)

Comment: I am not sure about that. But i found out that the problem is in height attribute. If you add height to .content_img div tag, that unclickable error happens. if you remove height, (width works) it works. Make no sense though... sorry for not being able to help to the end